# Add routes/special messages to akka router

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my application I have to send subscription messages to actors, which may or may not be routers. If they are routers, the messages have to be send to all routees. `Broadcast` is not applicable here, because the actors may not be routers and I don't want to handle `Broadcast` messages inside of the actors receive block. I also don't want to create a custom router, because the router can be of any type. So what I would like to do is something like this:

```
system.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withRouter(FromConfig().withRoute { routeeProvider => {
  case (sender, Subscribe) => routeeProvider.routees.map(Destination(sender, _))
}}))
```

Is there some way to do this, or any other way to add special routing behaviour like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a normal actor, have routees/actors dial-in and/or created as children and forward inbound messages as you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a parent abstract class for all your actors where you can handle all special messages needed and inherit all your non-router actors from it. Something like this:

```
abstract class MyActor extends Actor {

  protected def receiveMsg: Receive // will substitute "receive" in your actors

  def receive = receiveMsg orElse {

    case Broadcast(msg) => self ! msg

    ...

  }

}
```

Comment: I know, but that's not really what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is wrong with that? Btw, as actors can come and go, your subscription mechanism could be potentially racy. This might be a problem or not, but good to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Endre. I am aware of that possible race. The reason why I would like to put this in the router is, that it is routing related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BroadcastRouter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#BroadcastRouter) for your routers. Unlike other routers which only broadcast if the message is a broadcast message this router will broadcast every message to its children.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to broadcast a specific type of message.